# Can't upload an object with a nested array as a property in firestore / swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, mobile

**The object I am saving**

`customer: irelyn - items: ["Chicken Bacon Ranch", "BLT"] - total price: 17.30`

**ERROR IM GETTING**:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (FirebaseFirestoreSwift.FirestoreEncodingError error 0.)
```

**This is my code:**

```
//function to save the order 

    func saveItem(item: Order, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
        
    
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            do {
                let data = try encoder.encode(item)
                let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any] ?? [:]
                db.collection("items").addDocument(data: dictionary) { (error) in
                    completion(error)
                }
            } catch {
                completion(error)
            }
        }
    
}
```

**My Model for "Order" object:**

```
struct Order: Identifiable, Codable {
    
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    let customer: String
    let total: String
    let orderItems: [String]
    
}

//the menuitem objects -> im storing the name into an array for all the items being ordered in the object above 

struct MenuItem: Identifiable, Codable {
    
    var id: String?
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var price: Double
}


View Code: 
Button {
    
    //store the menu items
    let array: [MenuItem] = appVM.myCart
    let menuItems: [String]  = array.map { $0.name }
    
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    
    let price = appVM.totalAmount
    let orderTotal = formatter.string(for: price) ?? ""
    let user = loginVM.currentUser?.fullName
    
    //store the new order with total, name, and order
    let newOrder = Order(customer: user ?? "",total: orderTotal, orderItems: menuItems)
    
    print("customer: \(newOrder.customer) - items: \(newOrder.orderItems) - total price: \(newOrder.total)")
    
    
    appVM.saveItem(item: newOrder) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print("Success")
        }
    }
    
} label: {
    
    Text("Place My Order!")
        .bold()
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(30)
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .foregroundColor(.orange)
    
}
```

The data is all being created correctly its just the uploading if the data thats not working correctly. Tried numerous solutions, none worked. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, it was due to using firebase's @documentID as my id property

Comment: Using `@DocumentID var id: String?` with Objects allows those object to take advantage of [Mapping Firebase Objects with Codable](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/) so removing it doesn't sound like a good answer (if you're using codable). I suspect there was something else going on as that should not cause the issue being described.